# My Custom Polymer Element Fails To Render

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to make a custom Polymer element that extends `<paper-input-decorator>`. The intension is to have an input field that allows only a certain format of numbers, say a field for postal codes. So to achieve this, I extended paper-input-decorator and declare an  within it, but nothing is displayed on the screen. The code paste is here :  http://ur1.ca/jr70c

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. First of all, `paper-input-decorator` renders a lot of stuff in it’s shadow dom itself. Whether you want to see it, you *must* include parent shadow in template:

```
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ng-phone.css">
  <input is="core-input">
  <!-- ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ -->
  <shadow></shadow>  
</template>
```

Though now you are able to see both input and decorator, the result won’t suit your needs: the input is placed *above* the decorator. Quite predictable.

Instead of extending the decorator, you should create your own element and **use decorator in template** as shown in [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-input-decorator):

```
<polymer-element name="my-phone" attributes="myLabel">
  <template>
    <paper-input-decorator label="{{myLabel}}">
      <input is="core-input">
    </paper-input-decorator>    
  </template>
  ....
```

`myLabel` above will be automatically bound. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already figured it out and the component is here : http://goo.gl/5cTlmn I decided not to wrap the element with a paper-input-decorator since that may not be what the user wants, instead it extends core-input and can be wrapped with paper-input-decorator if the user so wishes. Thanks again.